# Facebook send API sending audio issue

Tags: python, json, facebook, audio

Can't send audio through facebook send api. It always returns with an HTTP 400 Bad Request. I use python and urllib for the http request.

Json:

```html
   'recipient':{
  'id' : userId
 },
 'message' : {
  'attachment' : {
   'type' : 'audio',
   'payload' : {
    'url' : url
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Request:

```
def send_msg(userId,data,accessKey):
    HEADERS = {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }
    url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='+accessKey
    msg_json = {
       'message' : {
        'attachment' : {
            'type' : 'audio',
            'payload' : {
                'url' : url
            }
        }
    }


    data = json.dumps(msg_json).encode('utf-8')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url,data,HEADERS)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

The code works on image and file attachment but it doesn't work on audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the json blueprint is the missing 'Content-type' that should have a value of 'audio/mpeg' that specifies the file format for the mp3 audio uploads